# Two questions about printing with SwingController

Tags: java, swing, printing

I use a class [SwingController](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/icepdf/v4_3_2/viewer/javadocs/org/icepdf/ri/common/SwingController.html) and method for *print().*

```
SwingController controller = new SwingController(); 
controller.print(true);
```

By default, the page will print format **Letter**.

1. How to change the format of the default page on **A4**?
2. How to change the background **color** of the print dialog? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `PrintHelper` can help. For [example](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/PDF/Print+Services+Example).

Comment: Thanks for comment, Aqua. This method suits me.

Comment: np, I am glad it helped :)

Comment: But, what you know about "2.How to change the background color of the print dialog?"

Comment: Do you mean the native print dialog? Why would you want to change its background? See [Using Print Setup Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html). Or there is another dialog you meant?

Comment: Omms, i don't know about native print dialog or not. Because my form has a another color. And I want the color of the print dialog was as the color of the form.